# update/extend mongoose document with object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a REST api client that I send and receive mongoose documents to as plain objects, serialized via JSON. The documents arent overly complex, but do contain embedded objects and arrays, like:

```
var doc = mongoose.Schema({
         doc_info: {
            current: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: true },
            edited_by: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
            create_date: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now() },
            save_date: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now() },
            prev_versions: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'DOC'}]
},
ix_info: {
        runid:  { type: String, required: true },
        agency_id: {type: Number, required: true},
        agency_ref: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Agency'},
        run_times:{
           recd: Date
        }
```

}...
}

When I receive a document back from a client, it will only be a partial document, as many things are not sent to it from the stored document. In the above snippet, the doc_info section is not sent to clients.  When I receive an object back from the client, I need to merge the document with the updated object. EVERYTHING in the object I get from the client is defined in the document's schema, but it is not a complete document, and I don't necessarily know what document properties are in the object, it can be one, a few, or many.

I tried using _.extend, but that results in any properties that are arrays or nested objects NOT in the received object being deleted from the document.  In the example schema above, pcr_info.prev_versions gets deleted when using `_.extend(doc, newObj)`.  Is there a way to blindly extend my document with an object without deleting things not in the source object?  Is this considered a 'deep merge' or 'deep copy' problem?

Comment: Yeah I think you have essentially a deep merge problem. I'm sure there are libraries available to help (like _.extend but support deep objects). However, realistically you'll probably end up writing a bunch of code due to application-specific business rules, authorization, validation, etc.

Comment: @PeterLyons Thanks. I tried lodash.merge which is supposed to be a deep extend, but it also deletes destination arrays if they don't exist in source.  Validation happens after all this, so it uses my normal schema validation rules.